# Angular Page rendering or lifecycle problem: SVGGraphicsElement.getScreenCTM returns wrong translation values when reentering the page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, svg

EDIT:
I realized this has to be an angular-only problem (not with the method/svgs in general inside a browser environment) since you can check in the minimal reproducible example the svg.html file inside the root folder, which you can open in the browser, it'll show the correct .f values. Probably something with how angular renders the page (especially after a component revisit).

I also removed the `<ion-content>` tags and it still happens. So not Ionic at fault?

---

I really wanna be able to get an svg-path elements position relative to the viewport. I need it to be able to use the panzoom method from timmywil/panzoom. I came up with this:

```
private getCenterRelativeToScreen(svgElement: MapLocationElement) {
  const {elemSvgX, elemSvgY} = this.getElemSvgXY(svgElement);
  console.log('elemSvgX/Y', elemSvgX, elemSvgY);
  // Convert local SVG coordinates to screen coordinates.
  const screenPoint = new DOMPointReadOnly(elemSvgX, elemSvgY);
  const globalPoint = screenPoint.matrixTransform(this.ctm);

  return {
    elemScreenX: globalPoint.x,
    elemScreenY: globalPoint.y
  };
}
```

This works as long as this.ctm is correct. BUT:

I am experiencing very strange behaviour from the `SVGGraphicsElement.getScreenCTM` method in general. It returns different values depending on when in the page lifecycle it is called.

in particular the translation is very off when I use Angular and RE-enter the page where the svg is.

I tested this with google chrome on windows 11.

I created a minimal reproducible example:
https://github.com/folsze/getScreenCTM-bug

TO TEST IT:

just go to the svg page, then go back, then enter it again. Check the console. It should all be very clear. Set your chrome window to responsive and 1000x500.

Note that the `e` (x-values) of the DOMMatrix stay consistently the same and are correct afaik. Only the `f` value (y-translation) is off. This is because the svg is 100% height and its size is then limited by the height of the page (not by the width of the page) thus the issue with different `f` values probably has to do with how the `SVGGraphicsElement.getScreenCTM` method calculates the margin in between the svg and the viewport border.

This is the code that tests the svg:

The following method is called inside ngAfterViewInit

```
  private testItAll() {
const fValuesSet = new Set<number>();

if (window.innerWidth !== 1000 || window.innerHeight !== 500) {
  throw new Error("Window dimensions are not 1000x500! Exiting calculation since value-checking if-statements dont make sense now.");
}

// NOTE: comment this in if you are using ng-inline-svg
// NOTE: this doesn't work, need setTimeout... The next get only assigns to mainWrapper
// this.mainWrapper = document.getElementById('main-wrapper') as unknown as SVGGElement;
// if (this.mainWrapper) {
//   this.ctm = this.mainWrapper.getScreenCTM()!;
//   this.log('\nright away worked (it actually shouldn\'t...!');
// }

setTimeout(() => {
  this.mainWrapper = document.getElementById('main-wrapper') as unknown as SVGGElement;
  this.ctm = this.mainWrapper.getScreenCTM()!;
  this.log('-----------------------------------AFTER 0ms:');

  fValuesSet.add(this.ctm.f);
  if (this.ctm.f > 20) {
    throw new Error('This shouldn\'t happen! Why is the y-translation suddenly: ' + this.ctm.f);
  } else {
    console.log('no error occured');
  }
}, 0);

setTimeout(() => {
  this.mainWrapper = document.getElementById('main-wrapper') as unknown as SVGGElement;
  this.ctm = this.mainWrapper.getScreenCTM()!;
  this.log('-----------------------------------AFTER 1ms:');

  fValuesSet.add(this.ctm.f);
  if (this.ctm.f > 20) {
    throw new Error('This shouldn\'t happen! Why is the y-translation suddenly: ' + this.ctm.f);
  } else {
    console.log('no error occured');
  }
}, 1);

setTimeout(() => {
  this.ctm = this.mainWrapper.getScreenCTM()!;
  this.log('-----------------------------------AFTER 10ms:');

  fValuesSet.add(this.ctm.f);
  if (this.ctm.f > 20) {
    throw new Error('This shouldn\'t happen! Why is the y-translation suddenly: ' + this.ctm.f);
  } else {
    console.log('no error occured');
  }
}, 10);

setTimeout(() => {
  this.ctm = this.mainWrapper.getScreenCTM()!;
  this.log('-----------------------------------AFTER 100ms:');

  fValuesSet.add(this.ctm.f);
  if (this.ctm.f > 20) {
    throw new Error('This shouldn\'t happen! Why is the y-translation suddenly: ' + this.ctm.f);
  } else {
    console.log('no error occured');
  }
  console.error('All different .f values, why are they not all the same?', [...fValuesSet]);
}, 100);
```

}

This is the code of the svg:

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">

<!--  NOTE: my app uses ng-inline-svg, but this even happens with 
normal svgs in template-->
<!--  <div-->
<!--    class="container"-->
<!--    inlineSVG="assets/example.svg"-->
<!--    [onSVGLoaded]="onSvgLoaded"-->
<!--  ></div>-->

<div class="container">
<svg
  version="1.1"
  id="svg13"
  viewBox="0 0 200 200"
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g
    stroke="#ff0000"
    id="main-wrapper">
    <rect
      x="26.778288"
      y="27.984278"
      width="141.49081"
      height="139.91692"
      fill="#0000ff"
      id="rect4"
      style="stroke-width:14.1411" />
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
<ion-button style="position: fixed; top: 40px; left: 0" 
(click)="calcAndLog()">log</ion-button>
<ion-button style="position: fixed; top: 200px; left: 0" 
(click)="goBack()">Go back</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used ionViewDidEnter and calculated the screenCTM only after it has entered. Now it works pretty well I think, thus far. But haven't tested heaps yet.